# how to save multiple dynamic textbox and dropdownlist values in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How do I save multiple dynamic textboxes and dropdownlist values in a database using asp.net?

**For that I used code below as follows :**

```
public partial class StockEntry : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList Ddl_Item;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Txt_Quantity;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList Ddl_Unit;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Txt_Available;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GoodMasterDetails();
            UnitMasterDetails();
        }
    }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["countTimes"] == null)
        {
            countTimes = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            countTimes = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["countTimes"]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < countTimes; i++)
        {
            Ddl_Item = new DropDownList();
            Ddl_Item.ID = "Ddl_Item";
            Ddl_Item.Width = 150 + i;
            Ddl_Item.Style[" margin-right"] = "14px";
            Ddl_Item.Style[" margin-left"] = "10px";
            BLL_StockEntry BLL = new BLL_StockEntry();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = BLL.GoodsMasterDetails();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Ddl_Item.DataSource = dt;
                Ddl_Item.DataTextField = "GM_NAME";
                Ddl_Item.DataValueField = "GM_ID";
                Ddl_Item.DataBind();
                Ddl_Item.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", string.Empty));
            }

            Txt_Quantity = new TextBox();
            Txt_Quantity.ID = "Txt_Quantity" + countTimes;
            Txt_Quantity.Width = 150 + i;
            Txt_Quantity.Style[" margin-right"] = "14px";
            //Txt_Quantity.Style[" margin-left"] = "0px";

            Ddl_Unit = new DropDownList();
            Ddl_Unit.ID = "Ddl_Unit" + countTimes;
            Ddl_Unit.Width = 150 + i;
            Ddl_Unit.Style[" margin-right"] = "14px";
            Ddl_Unit.Style[" margin-left"] = "10px";
            BLL_StockEntry BLLL = new BLL_StockEntry();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1 = BLLL.UnitsMasterDetails();
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Ddl_Unit.DataSource = dt1;
                Ddl_Unit.DataTextField = "UM_UNITNAME";
                Ddl_Unit.DataValueField = "UM_ID";
                Ddl_Unit.DataBind();
                Ddl_Unit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", string.Empty));
            }

            Txt_Available = new TextBox();
            Txt_Available.ID = "Txt_Available" + countTimes;
            Txt_Available.Width = 150 + i;
            Txt_Available.Style[" margin-right"] = "14px";
            //Txt_Available.Style[" margin-left"] = "10px";

            dvContainer.Controls.Add(Ddl_Item);
            dvContainer.Controls.Add(Txt_Quantity);

            dvContainer.Controls.Add(Ddl_Unit);
            dvContainer.Controls.Add(Txt_Available);

        }
        countTimes = countTimes + 1;

        ViewState.Add("countTimes", countTimes);
    }

 private void StockEntryBind(string mode)
    {
        PL.RESTURENT.PL_StockEntry objpl = new PL.RESTURENT.PL_StockEntry();

        objpl.StockEntryId = HiddenField1.Value.ToString();

        objpl.Date = DateTime.Parse(txt_date.Text);

        objpl.Time = txt_time.Text;

        objpl.Godown = Ddl_Godown.SelectedItem.Text;

        objpl.Item = Ddl_Items.SelectedItem.Text;//static

        string str = string.Empty;//dynamic
        DropDownList ddlitem = (DropDownList)dvContainer.FindControl("Ddl_Item") as DropDownList;
        str = ddlitem.SelectedItem.Text;

        objpl.Quantity = Txt_Quantity.Text;

        objpl.Unit = Ddl_Unit.SelectedItem.Text;

        objpl.AvailableStock = Txt_Available.Text;

        objpl.mode = mode;

        BLL_StockEntry objbll = new BLL_StockEntry();
        if (objbll.StockEntryTransaction(objpl))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "Alert('Pay    Slip Inserted Succesfully...')", true);
        }
    }
```

I have tried only for (dropdownlist)Ddl_Item to insert data in database but

```
str = ddlitem.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

I am declaring method to call in button event through mode type using dynamic stored procedure.

Comment: when are you calling StockEntryBind() ? after another postback?

Answer (score 0):

Try THis...

```
((TextBox)Page.Form.FindControl("Your TextBox Id")).Text
```